# How to toggle between two elements using single React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

How to toggle between two elements using a single React state? Right now both of the elements are toggled via `onPress` but should toggle only one at a time.

```
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
    
  function toggle() {
    setActive((active) => !active);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <CustomButton onPress={toggle} active={active} />
      <CustomButton onPress={toggle} active={active} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Make one of them `active={!active}`

Comment: Thanks it works! What would be the solution if i would need them both to be selected separately and not switching from one to the other?

Comment: Then you would need two different states to control them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like below ... as Hao said

```
    const [active, setActive] = React.useState("");

    function toggle(name) {
        setActive(name);
    }

    return (
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <CustomButton onPress={()=>toggle("one")} active={active === "one"}/>
                    <CustomButton onPress={()=>toggle("two")} active={active === "two"}/>
                </View>
           );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the toggle functions should be the opposite for both of the elements. `one` toggles `two` and vice versa

Comment: @HaoWu yeah maybe, that was not clear from Q 